# 2000 Jeep Grand Cherokee Electrical Problem

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting, jeep, grand-cherokee

This problem is a very strange one. Completely unsure of what is causing it. All passenger electrics do not work, drivers electric lock and window work sometimes, other times don’t. Usually the drivers side door window works for the 10 seconds after starting the car. The ABS and Brake lights are both on. Also the key fob stopped working at the same time.

Comment: Check the wiring leading to the drivers door - that has all the other doors linked to it ...

Comment: As for the console, that is an old problem and should be a separate question...